# Find a smooth function that maximizes a composite likelihood function

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, curve-fitting

I need to find a smooth function $f$ that maximizes an objective function $g$ over its predictions on a predefined set of values $p$:
\begin{equation}
f^*=\arg\max_{f} g(f(.),p,X)
\end{equation}
In particular, $g$ is very similar to a likelihood function using $X$ as data and $f(p)$ as parameters. The only difference with regular parametric fitting is that the data comes from multiple distributions but within a same family (e.g. several beta-binomials), rather than a single distribution. $X_i$ and $X_j$ come from the same distribution if $p_i$=$p_j$. For example, if X's come from the beta-binomial parametric family:
\begin{equation}
f(p_i)=(\alpha_i, \beta_i) \\
X_i \sim \textit{Beta-Binomial}(f(p_i))
\end{equation}
So $f(.)$ is a function that determines which distribution $X_i$ comes from by mapping $p_i$ to parameters of that distribution. The goal is to find $f$ that maximizes likelihood over all data, coming from multiple distributions with different parameters.
To summarize,  $X$ which is used in the likelihood function is given, and for each $X_i$, there is a $p_i$ given as well. Function $f(.)$ which maps $p_i$ to the parameters of the  distribution for $X_i$ is unknown.

This seems like a very simple problem, but I spent a few hours searching for packages in R or in Python and could not find a solution. There must be a solution, because it simply boils down to finding a function that maximizes a custom objective function over all given $p$ values. Assuming we use $l(\alpha, \beta; X_i)$ to represent the log-likelihood associated with the distribution family, the problem becomes:
\begin{equation}
f^*=\arg\max_{f} \sum_i l(f(p_i);X_i)
\end{equation}
This is exactly the same as normal parametric fit, with the only difference that instead of a single set of parameters, we are finding a function that maps to our parameters.

Any pointer to R packages would be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be asking for references to generic multivariate minimizers, but that isn't very clear due to the vague, general problem statement and internal inconsistencies (e.g., is $f$ fully general or is it parameterized; do you mean to *minimize* the objective or *maximize* it as explicitly given in the formula?).  Do you have a specific problem you could describe?

Comment: @whuber I added more clarification. Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Are you perhaps describing a multilevel or hierarchical probability model?

Comment: @Sycorax Yes, this can be thought of a non-bayesian hierarchical model. p determines the top-level hierarchy, but the challenge is that it is a continuous variable.

Comment: So perhaps it's more like a mixture model.

Comment: I don’t understand what is known and unknown. What are you minimizing over? I thought it was $f(\cdot)$, but your last paragraph suggests $f(\cdot)$ is known? Also do you know which distribution each $X$ belongs to or do you need to estimate that too?

Comment: @Eli Sorry for the confusion. I realize the last paragraph was confusing, so I edited the question. You are correct, the unknown is the function _f_. We know that each _X_ comes from the same parametric family (e.g. binomial), but we don't know its parameters. _X_'s with the same _p_ share the same parameter value, and _X_'s with different _p_'s can come from different distributions.